# Problem updating table with SOQL

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I want to update Notes__c. It's a textarea field so I assume I want to pass a String value into it, but in order to write my query, I have to declare 'myNote' as a List.

At the moment I receive this error:

```
'Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from String to LIST<Database
-obj__c>'
```

Im assuming it's because I'm trying to pass a string into 'myNote'.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
   List<Database_obj__c> myNote;

   public PageReference updateNote() { 
    myNote = [SELECT Notes__c 
              FROM Database_obj__c 
              WHERE Id = :id];

    myNote = 'SUCCESS';

    try {
        update myNote;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        system.debug('Error: ' + ex);
    }

    return null;    
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to assign a value to the `Notes__c` field from the selected `myNote` object:

```
// Here you don't need to define a list variable decause your query returns only one record
Database_obj__c myNote;

public PageReference updateNote() { 
    myNote = [SELECT Notes__c 
              FROM Database_obj__c 
              WHERE Id = :id];

    myNote.Notes__c = 'SUCCESS';

    try {
        update myNote;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        system.debug('Error: ' + ex);
    }

    return null;    
}
```

Comment: Cheers mast0r! You saved me hours of screen shaking :)